# JAXB: Intercept during unmarshalling?

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I've got a typical web service using JAX-RS and JAXB, and upon unmarshalling I would like to know which setters were explicitly called by JAXB.  This effectively lets me know which elements were included in the document provided by the caller.

I know I can probably solve this with an `XmlAdapter`, but I have a lot of classes in a number of different packages, and I don't want to create adapters for each and every one of them.  Nor do I want to put hooks into each and every setter.  I would like a general solution if possible.  Note that all of my classes are setup to use getters and setters; none of them use fields for the access type.

My service uses Jersey 2.4, Spring 3.2, and MOXy 2.5.1, so if there's anything that can be leveraged from any of those, that's all the better.  Our original thought was we could dynamically create a factory class (akin to what `@XmlType` supports) that would return a proxy object that would intercept the setters.  We thought we could make this happen using the `MetadataSource` concept in MOXy, but that does not seem to be possible.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My service uses Jersey 2.4, Spring 3.2, and MOXy 2.5.1, so if there's
>   anything that can be leveraged from any of those, that's all the
>   better.

### Create your own EclipseLink `AttributeAccessor`

MOXy (which is a component of EclipseLink) leverages a class called `AttributeAccessor` to do operations with fields and properties.  You could wrap this class to capture all the information that you need.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.AttributeAccessor;

public class MyAttributeAccessor extends AttributeAccessor {

    private AttributeAccessor attributeAccessor;

    public MyAttributeAccessor(AttributeAccessor attributeAccessor) {
        this.attributeAccessor = attributeAccessor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAttributeValueFromObject(Object domainObject)
            throws DescriptorException {
        return attributeAccessor.getAttributeValueFromObject(domainObject);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttributeValueInObject(Object domainObject, Object value)
            throws DescriptorException {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - Set value:  " + value + " on property: " + attributeAccessor.getAttributeName() + " for object: " + domainObject);
        attributeAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(domainObject, value);
    }

}
```

### Tell MOXy to use your `AttributeAccessor`

We can leverage a `SessionEventListener` to access the underlying metadata to specify your implementation of `AttributeAccessor`.  This is passed in as a property when creating the `JAXBContext`.

```
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.SESSION_EVENT_LISTENER, new SessionEventAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void postLogin(SessionEvent event) {
            Project project = event.getSession().getProject();
            for(ClassDescriptor descriptor : project.getOrderedDescriptors()) {
                for(DatabaseMapping mapping : descriptor.getMappings()) {
                    mapping.setAttributeAccessor(new MyAttributeAccessor(mapping.getAttributeAccessor()));
                }
            }
            super.preLogin(event);
        }

    });

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);
```

### Leverage a JAX-RS `ContextResolver` when Creating the `JAXBContext`

Since you are in a JAX-RS environment you can leverage a `ContextResolver` to control how the `JAXBContext` is created.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html

---

### Standalone Example

**Java Model (Foo)**

Below is a sample class where we will use field access (no setters).

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private String bar;
    private String baz;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.SESSION_EVENT_LISTENER, new SessionEventAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void postLogin(SessionEvent event) {
                Project project = event.getSession().getProject();
                for(ClassDescriptor descriptor : project.getOrderedDescriptors()) {
                    for(DatabaseMapping mapping : descriptor.getMappings()) {
                        mapping.setAttributeAccessor(new MyAttributeAccessor(mapping.getAttributeAccessor()));
                    }
                }
                super.preLogin(event);
            }

        });

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<foo><bar>Hello World</bar></foo>");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Thread: 1 - Set value:  Hello World on property: bar for object: forum21044956.Foo@37e47e38
```

---

### UPDATE

> So this works, but I have a few issues. First, the domainObject is
>   always logging as 0 in my system. Not sure why that's occurring.

I have not idea why that is occuring, may need to check the `toString()` for the object you are logging.

> Second, I am not able to tell if the property in question is on the
>   top-level item that is being unmarshalled or on a sub-element. That's
>   actually quite annoying.

You will need to beef up the logic here.  Based on the objects being set you should be able to do what you want.

> Third, your solution is per JAXBContext, but I don't know if I really
>   want to create a new context for every request. Isn't that bad from an
>   overhead perspective?

You can cache the created `JAXBContext` to prevent rebuilding it.

Comment: This looks interesting.  I'll have to try it and get back to you.  Thanks!

Comment: So this works, but I have a few issues.  First, the `domainObject` is always logging as `0` in my system.  Not sure why that's occurring.  Second, I am not able to tell if the property in question is on the top-level item that is being unmarshalled or on a sub-element.  That's actually quite annoying.  Third, your solution is per `JAXBContext`, but I don't know if I really want to create a new context for every request.  Isn't that bad from an overhead perspective?

Comment: @StevenM.Wurster - I have updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: I'll check the `toString()` on my class.  I'm sure it's limited for my test class.  I'm still not sure how I'll determine the sub-elements, but I'll do some investigating.  If you have any advice on that let me know.  The issue I have with caching the `JAXBContext` is that we want to 'catch' the properties for each request.  If we cache the `JAXBContext` instances won't we have the same instance handling multiple requests?  I'm sure we can work around that somehow however.

Comment: In the meantime I will accept this answer.  Definitely answered my question.