# How to capture the field when creating an xml from an object which throws a jaxb exception?

Tags: exception, jaxb

Is there a way to capture the exact field when creating an xml from an object which throws a jaxb exception due to some field being null?

I have multiple fields with the same object as list with different name and value pairs. Like customfield name1 and value, customfield name2 and value etc. Here customfield is the tag.

I want to know which custom field exactly gave the error. Would I be able to capture this error during marshalling?

Right now, it just throws, value is necessary.

Is there any way to capture the exact steps?

Comment: If you are using EclipseLink MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider then the following approach may work for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044956/jaxb-intercept-during-unmarshalling/21046280#21046280

Comment: Thanks @BlaiseDoughan. I don't think this will be feasible for our code. But i will surely try it out for my own purpose..